# Upgrading to SSL when site is public and all backlinks are Http

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https

I use BlueHost for LearnInternetGrow.com and I have all www addresses being redirected to non www. I did this so that my organic search results would start with my domain name.

I recently set up SSL for the site but may not keep it in the long run.

I have backlinks that are hard coded with http://learninternetgrow.com. I want to redirect all types of variations of the address

(http://learninternetgrow.com http://www.learninternetgrow.com https://www.learninternetgrow.com)

to https://learninternetgrow.com. I want to do it this way so that if I get rid of SSL (which comes with a premium) I don't have to get Google to recrawl the site and redo all the backlinks.

I feel like my logic may be faulty. Has anyone used a 301 redirect to send all traffic to a secure version of their site. I started without SSL because the site is just a blog without any sign ins, but I read that SEO can get a boost if I use SSL. So this is really a test to see if the premium is worth the SEO bump. If it isn't I will get rid of it but I want to minimize the work necessary for this test.

Please let me know if you have done a similar test and how you did it. If you started with an http site and upgraded to TLS (SSL) how did you go about doing it without hurting your organic traffic.

The main questions is - When upgrading to SSL on WordPress, should one redirect to Https at the server level or change wordpress settings - WordPRess address URL to https:// or should I do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that "boost" your https but do done properly :

- 301 (permanent) redirect
- Avoid mixed content

So you need to change the wordpress address in the settings to avoid mixed content, and add the 301 redirect directly in the server configuration if possible.

Wait at least 2 week before start looking for a boots. The boost will be small but don't forget :

https is *not* about SEO boost, it's about security of your visitor and integrity of your website (some ISP inject ads inside http websites...)